# Django URL Config - Match filename

Tags: python, django

Using Django 1.5.1 I'm trying to match:

```
/uploads/view/FILE_NAME.ext  eg: /uploads/view/testfile.png
```

Currently:

```
uploads_url_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^uploads/view/(?P<file_name>\w{0,256})/$', ShowImageView.as_view(), name='show'),
)
```

However it doesn't match `/uploads/view/testfile.png`.

As i'm still struggling to understand python regex's how can i match so i end up with a string including the filename and its extension or even better, its filename and extension separately?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\w` does not match `.`, so the `.png` extension is not being matched. Add the `.` dot to your character class. You want to drop the trailing slash as well:

```
uploads_url_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^uploads/view/(?P<file_name>[\w.]{0,256})$', ShowImageView.as_view(), name='show'),
)
```

This now will match the literal text `uploads/view/` followed by between 0 and 256 letters, digits, underscores and dots.

Quick demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'^uploads/view/(?P<file_name>[\w.]{0,256})$', 'uploads/view/test_filename.png')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x103aa5828>
>>> re.search(r'^uploads/view/(?P<file_name>[\w.]{0,256})$', 'uploads/view/test_filename.png').groupdict()
{'file_name': 'test_filename.png'}
```

Comment: Dot means 'any character'. May be it's better to use [\w\.]{0,256}?

Comment: @sergzach: Not in a character class it does not. Within `[...]` it is *just* a dot.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, it worked.. what would you suggest to grab the filename and the extension separately, like file_name => "test_filename", extension => "png"?

Comment: @Daniel: Add on a separate extension pattern on to the end, or just use `os.path.splitext()` in your view to extract the extension.